# Returning values from AJAX(with jQuery.ajax) callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to retrieve a value from asynchronous ajax. I came up with the code:

```
function getInfoChannels(name){
  return $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + name,
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp"
  });
}

var logo;  

getInfoChannels(name).done(function(json){
  logo = json.logo;
  });

console.log('image link from getInfoChannels: '+logo)
```

which logs `image link from getInfChannels: undefined` instead the link.

I'm very new to JS. In my former fun little projects i managed to cramp all my data manipulation inside the `.done()`. But this time I  want the link to the logo outside of it.

Comment: _" In my former fun little projects i managed to cramp all my data manipulation inside the `.done()`"_  Keep doing that.  That's the right way of doing it, or at least call a callback from within `done`.

Comment: Read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/